# mounting a directory for pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application which accesses a couple of files from a directory. I went through kubernetes volumes and persistent volumes and volume claims. this is a multi-node kubernetes cluster. do we have any direct solution which can be used which does not need any external storage like a nfs server etc?

I have a VM server from where i execute my kubernetes commands. I am new to kubernetes so please help me with this.

Also i was looking at local persistent volume. is there a link which i can go through for an example. I am looking at local https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local

But the example does not explain what below are under nodeAffinity:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - example-node
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your use case, if the files you want to share across the cluster are more than a few megabytes in size, you'll need some kind of storage operator. Local storage is probably not what you're looking for.

---

### For small files (configs, keys, init scripts)

If the files are small, such as configuration files or ssh keys or similar you can use a kubernetes configmap (or secret). This will allow you to setup a few files or directories with a few files. [Checkout the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

---

### For large files (shared data, graphics, binaries)

If however you want to share a few hundred megabytes or gigabytes of files, you need a storage provider with your cluster.

If you are using a cloud provider, such as Google, AWS or Azure, this should be straightforward, you need to create a persistent disk with your cloud provider and copy your required data onto the disk. Once that's done, simply follow the guide for the relevant cloud providers:

- Google Cloud - [GCE Persistent Disk](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk)
- <strike>AWS - [Elastic Block Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#awselasticblockstore)</strike>
- <strike>Azure - [Azure Disk](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#azuredisk)</strike>

(@justcompile pointed out that AWS doesn't support multiple read-only mounts to instances, I was unable to find similar information for Azure)

If however, you're running your own kubernetes cluster on "baremetal", you'll have to setup either an NFS server, a [Ceph cluster](https://ceph.com/) and probably use something like [rook](https://github.com/rook/rook) on top.

Comment: I can't speak for the others as I'm not overly familiar with them, but you can't mount an AWS EBS volume to more than 1 EC2 instance. 
Given the OP is talking about a multi-node cluster, unless they want to taint or force pods to run on particular nodes, EBS wouldn't be suitable....and their EFS (NFS variant) is awful

Comment: @ffledgling Thanks a lot for this information. We are running our own kubernetes cluster. So i guess as per your suggestion we might have to go ahead with NFS server. do you happen to have anything on procuring or setting up a NFS server and related config form Kubernetes

Comment: @justcompile, I think you might be right. I was under the impression that EBS (like GCP's perisistent disk), could be mounted to multiple instances when it's supposed to be read-only. Looks like EBS does not support that, which is a little surprising, but a good caveat to know.

Comment: @AnilKumarP, Sorry, that'd be too broad a question to answer in the comments. I'd recommend you try setting up ceph instead of NFS anyway, since it's easy to do inside the kubernetes cluster, following the instructions here - http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/kube-helm/